# MSBuild not building all targets in true parallel manner

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, msbuild

Let me first brief the structure of our project.

We have a single CMakeLists.txt which has multiple library targets (added via add*library) and multiple exe targets (added via add_*executable) and each exe has multiple dependencies of libraries defined in same CMakeLists.txt.

We are statically linking libraries to exe. And our libraries are defined in layerd manner. So to access any lower layer artifact we do include lower ONE master header which includes all headers of the lower layer. For every layer/library, we are using target_precompile_headers like below

target_precompile_headers(UpperLayerLib Private /LowerLayerLib.hpp)

For Windows build, we are using Visual Studio Generator. So when CMake Cache generation is completed it in terns creates a sln (ProjectName.sln) and multiple vcxproj files for each target created via add_library, add_executable, etc..

To build our target we are using cmake like below.

1. Building a single library -> This builds find and I see it uses all cores cmake

`cmake --build --preset=<BuildPresetName> --parallel --target LibA -- /p:CL_MPcount=<logicalCores> and above command actually runs the below command using MsBuild C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe /m /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /p:CL_MPcount=16 /v:m LibA.vcxproj`

2. Building exe target with multiple dependent target: This builds find and I see it uses all cores

`cmake --build --preset=<BuildPresetName> --parallel --target ExeTarget-- /p:CL_MPcount=<logicalCores> and above command actually runs the below command using MsBuild C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe /m /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /p:CL_MPcount=16 /v:m ExeTarget.vcxproj`

What I found in this it started building all dependent targets in parallel. And I could also see multiple instance of MSBuild and cl.exe in task manager. Also noticed that till build complete it uses almost 100% CPU.

3. Building multiple independent library targets : This one seems that not building in true parallel

`cmake --build --preset=<BuildPresetName> --parallel --target LibA;LibB;LibC;LibD -- /p:CL_MPcount=<logicalCores>`

and the above command actually spawns 4 MSBuild instance and started building with logs like below

```
C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe /m /m /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /p:CL_MPcount=16 /v:m TWDevSupport.vcxproj
   MSBuild logs and debug information will be at "C:\Users\mohsin.siddiqui\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildTempmohsin.siddiqui\MSBuild_Logs"
     Checking Build System
     Building Custom Rule D:/TW/Workspace/CMakeLists.txt
     cmake_pch.cxx
    <bunch_of_cpp_files>
     TWDevSupport.vcxproj -> D:\TW\Builds\TWLib\Windows-x64\Debug\TWDevSupport.lib
   
   C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe /m /m /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /p:CL_MPcount=16 /v:m TWUniversal.vcxproj
   MSBuild logs and debug information will be at "C:\Users\mohsin.siddiqui\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildTempmohsin.siddiqui\MSBuild_Logs"
     Building Custom Rule D:/TW/Workspace/CMakeLists.txt
     cmake_pch.cxx
    <bunch_of_cpp_files>
     TWUniversal.vcxproj -> D:\TW\Builds\TWLib\Windows-x64\Debug\TWUniversal.lib
   
   C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe /m /m /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0  /p:CL_MPcount=16 /v:m TWCore.vcxproj
   MSBuild logs and debug information will be at "C:\Users\mohsin.siddiqui\AppData\Local\Temp\MSBuildTempmohsin.siddiqui\MSBuild_Logs"
     Building Custom Rule D:/TW/Workspace/CMakeLists.txt
     cmake_pch.cxx
     <bunch_of_cpp_files
     TWCore.vcxproj -> D:\TW\Builds\TWLib\Windows-x64\Debug\TWCore.lib
   ========= Build Successful =========
   Elapsed time: 9586 Milliseconds
```

We can easily see in the above logs that targets are not built in parallel. What arongI am doing is that my independent targets are not built in parallel.

If I build multiple targets selecting via project.sln (via Visual Studio IDE ) it works as expected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: By 'targets' do you mean projects, i.e. *.*proj files? When you build in Visual Studio, is CMake involved? I'm guessing Visual Studio is not using CMake and is running MSBuild on the solution file, project.sln, and the solution file has references to the projects: TWDevSupport.vcxproj, TWUniversal.vcxproj, and TWCore.vcxproj. If that is the case, then the MSBuild process can parallelize the projects because it has been given multiple projects to build. When CMake spawns an MSBuild process per project file, the MSBuild process doesn't know about the other projects.

Comment: @JonathanDodds by targets I mean *.*proj files . We have our extension on Visual Studio for building our project and in that while building we do use cmake to build. Yes Visual Studio builds does not use CMake.  The way Visual Studio handles multiple project build in parallel, I beleive cmake should also handle builds in parallel. I guess Visual Studio creates another target for selected targets as project reference and build that.. As Builds MSBuild projects from another MSBuild project

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2022

Comment: When MSBuild is given a .sln file, it creates a [meta project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2022#troubleshooting) in memory from the .sln file. The meta project builds the projects in the solution in-process. You can build the solution from the command line with `msbuild ProjectName.sln /m /p:Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64;CL_MPcount=16`. Maybe CMake is not adding value?